# changing the adress of the pointer through another pointer

Tags: c++

Heloo GUYS ..I am passing an alias to pointer in function and in that function i am assigning pointer to another variable .This is changing the address of the pointer passed in main funtion .i'll show u example of my code .This gives the output 40.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo(int* &p){
    int z=40;
    p=&z;
}
int main(){
    int x=10;
    int *p=&x;  
    foo(p);
    cout<<*p;
}
```

But when I try to do this all in one main function then the address of the the pointer doesnt change so as the ouput..this is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
    {
       int a=1, b=2, c=3;
       int *p, *q;
       p=&a;
       q=*&p;
       p=&c;
       cout<<*q<<endl;

    }
```

it gives the ouput 1 rather then the 3.THANKs..

Comment: Your first example has undefined behaviour.

Comment: That's because you aren't changing `q`.  You are changing `p`.

Comment: `q=*&p;` is the same as `q = p;`

Comment: c++ doesn't time travel. just because you do `p=&c` doesn't change the fact that `q` ended up pointing at `a`'s value in the previous line.

Comment: If you want to do "the same", it would look more like this: `int* p = &a; int*& q = p; q = &c; cout << *p;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void foo(int* &p){
    int z=40;
    p=&z;
}
```

Here `p`is a **reference** to a pointer. Which means that when you modify it you will modify the referred pointer too.

When you call `foo` with

```
int main(){
    int x=10;
    int *p=&x;  
    foo(p);
    cout<<*p;
}
```

You're saying that the **reference** named `p`in the function `foo` refers to the pointer named `p`in the function `main`so whatever you do to `p` in `foo`will affect `p` in `main`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
    {
       int a=1, b=2, c=3;
       int *p, *q;
       p=&a;
       q=*&p;
       p=&c;
       cout<<*q<<endl;

    }
```

Here you have no reference anywhere, you just have a pointer that you **copy** to another pointer. `q=*&p`is equivalent to `q=p`.

**The key difference to note here is that the `&` operator in the first exemple means "reference" while the `&` operator in the second example means "address of".**

If you want the closest equivalent to the first sample with the second one, try this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int a=1, b=2, c=3;
  int *p, *&q = p;
  p=&a;
  q=*&p;
  p=&c;
  cout<<*q<<endl;

}
```

And in this last case you have both an `&` which means "reference" in `int *p, *&q = p;` and an `&` that means "address of" in `q=*&p;`

Answer (score 0):

```
void foo(int* &p){
    int z=40;
    p=&z;
}
```

The above code is *not safe* because whoever called `foo` now has a pointer to a destroyed stack variable.

> it gives the ouput 1 rather then the 3.THANKs..

Of course it does. Learn what a pointer is and how it works.

```
int a=1, b=2, c=3, *p, **q;
p=&a;
q=&p;
p=&c;
std::cout << **q << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

just thought you should know that in foo() you're assigning the pointer to the address of a variable with automatic storage duration, which means that what it points to when foo returns is actually undefined (and in a larger program this is a disaster waiting to happen).

In your second example you only assign q once. During an assignment, a reference *is* the object it's referring to. The reference dependency is not carried forward.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you aren't changing `q`.  You are changing `p`.  When you do

```
q=*&p;
```

it is the same as

```
q = p;
```

So what you have done is assigned `p` to point to `a`.  Then you assign the value of `p` to `q` so now `q` points to `a`.  Then you assign the address of `c` to `p`.  Doing that does nothing to `q` and as such `q` still points to `a`.

You should also read [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) to see why your first example has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect to get the answer as `3`?

[image]

`q` points to `p` then you changed where `p` points. `p` points to c but `q` will still point to where previous address of `p`.

unless you reassign `q` to point to `p`, it will still point to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me only consider your second example and I added a few comments and hopefully it will clarify why you are getting that output.

```
   int a=1, b=2, c=3;
   int *p, *q;
   p=&a; //P now points to the variable a
   q=*&p; // q now points to the value in pointer p
   p=&c;
   cout<<*q<<endl; //You are printing  value from pointer q
```

Please note you are not changing the address of a pointer, instead you are changing only the address  where  pointer points to.